# Backup Exec not overwriting 'IMG000000' folders

Tags: backupexec

I'm using Backup Exec 12.5 to backup to Removable Backup-to-Disk Folders.

As part of this backup, it's creating folders in the root of backup disk, called `IMG000243`, as well as the `.bkf` files in `Veritas\B2D`.

I'm pretty sure these folders are being created as part of an Exchange 2007 Granular backup.

The problem is, they're not being overwritten when it comes time.  They're showing as part of the correct Media Set, with the correct append and overwrite dates, but if they need to be overwritten during a backup, they seem to be ignored and Backup-Exec starts asking for free space.

Currently, I'm manually wiping the disks before running the backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's been my experience as well. They are part of the GRT backups and my guess is that, as opposed to a tape, each folder is a unique logical construct and therefore BE just continues to create new ones. A tape is not unique in the sense that it is a physical construct and once the overwrite protection period expires it can be rewritten to... BE can't create a new tape, so to speak, but it can create new IMG folders.

I wrote a batch file that runs once a week via a scheduled task to run an rd command on the B2D folder that holds the IMG folders to get rid of them. Below is a snippet of the batch file:

> move
>   E:\B2DFullExchangeBackupFolder*.cfg
>   E:\Temp
>
> rd E:\B2DFullExchangeBackupFolder /S
>   /Q
>
> md E:\B2DFullExchangeBackupFolder
>
> move E:\Temp*.cfg
>   E:\B2DFullExchangeBackupFolder

Where **B2DFullExchangeBackupFolder** is the B2D folder. The reason I move the *.cfg file is so that BE doesn't have to recreate it, although I believe it will upon a BE service stop\start or restart.

Comment: Wow, that was fast...

Comment: I have to say that my theory is just a theory. I've never taken the time to research why BE behaves the way it does. The batch file does the trick so... case closed.